# Changing heading text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the text in one of my headings using jQuery, but it just leaves the heading blank. How would I get this to work?

Edit:

html page with heading:

```
<!-- Logs -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page15">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Logs
            </h3>
            <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide" href="#page3" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                Back
            </a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
            <a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="#page1">
                Add log entry
            </a>
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="" data-content-theme="">
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3>
                        July 2012
                    </h3>
                    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="" data-content-theme="">
                        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" onclick="getLogTime(); this.onclick=null">
                            <h3>
                                July 5
                            </h3>
                            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="" data-content-theme="">
                                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" onclick="getLogData(); this.onclick=null">
                                    //Heading I'm trying to change
                                    <h3 id=time1>
                                    </h3>
                                    <div>
                                        <p id="logFortime1">
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                                    <h3>
                                        12:47 pm
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                            <h3>
                                July 6
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3>
                        August 2012
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="#page21">
                Graphs
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Function that is supposed to change heading:

```
function getLogTime() {
$('#time1').text('Time')
}
```

Edit:

Added a = so the text in the header now changes, but it loses all of its styling and the contents in the collapsible menu.

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/landau/b9ggb/

Comment: Are you running the code within`$(document).ready(function () { ... });` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use either a tag name or an ID (preferred). Do NOT combine multiple selectors (especially since you should never have more than one ID in the DOM at any moment). The html() method is much faster than the text() method (see http://jsperf.com/jq2-text-vs-html), but, semantically, text() is more appropriate. **Make sure that the DOM has loaded before executing any code (for the DOM).** The following is the fastest, and should work.

```
$(function(){
  $("#time1").html("Time");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a pure jQuery solution ? Rather than giving onclick attirbutes on clickable elements you can simply use jQuery in this way.

HTML :

```
<h3 id="time1">Deepak</h3>
<a id='changeheading'>click</a>
```

JavaScript/jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#changeheading').on("click",function(){    
$('#time1').text('Time');
});
});​
```

And it works very fine. Check the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/b9ggb/25/